# ProgressDialog doesn't show with I using intent in Android

Tags: android

Everything is working fine, and the second Activity is running but My progress Dialog doesn't appear  when I using Intent.
Is there an error in the code? , I can't find stack.

an idea ???
Please help me , Thanks!

```js
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Intent mIntent;
    private final int totalProgressTime = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }   

    public void onClick(View view) {

        new DownloadTask().execute();
        mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mIntent);

    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Object>{

        ProgressDialog  mIndicator = new ProgressDialog(StartActivity.this);


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mIndicator.setMessage("Wait..");
            mIndicator.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mIndicator.setProgress(0);
            mIndicator.setMax(totalProgressTime );
            mIndicator.show();


            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    int counter = 0;
                    while(counter < totalProgressTime ){
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(300);
                            counter ++;
                            mIndicator.setProgress(counter);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    mIndicator.dismiss();
                }
            }).start();

        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);

            mIndicator.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's not talk about how wrong is to use AsyncTask as you used it here. I suppose you have some bigger picture, and this is just some test snippet.

So with

```
new DownloadTask().execute();
```

you started AsyncTask.

And just after that you started new activity:

```
mIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

So, AsyncTask continue to work in separate thread, but StartActivity is no longer active (probably not even visible), because MainActivity is in foreground now.

So, you want to see ProgressBar in StartActivity, but you are in MainActivity.

Try to wait AsyncTask to finish, than start MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    mIndicator.dismiss();
    mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
```